# Redraw dependent select list on client side

Tags: c#, jquery, razor

I have two dimensional array into Model View:

```
public class MyData
{
    public IList<Source> Sources
    { get; set; }

    // ...
}

public class Source 
{
    public string ParentName
    { get; set; }

    public IList<string> ChildNames
    { get; set; }
}
```

It would be about 5 parents and each of them has about 10 children. On the page I need to show 2 lists: the first would contain parents and the second would contain selected parent children.

```
<select id="parents">
@foreach (var source in Model.Sources)
{
    <option>@source</option>
}
</select>

<select id="childs">

</select>
```

Sources have formed at once on the server side and never modified. What is the best practice to show these lists? Could i redraw child list on the client side? How to get Model View into javascript(jQuery)? Something like this C# code:

```
Model.Sources.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ParentName == selectedValue)
```

into change event handler:

```
$("#parents").change(function () {

    var selectedValue = $("#parents").val();

    // ???
});
```

I'd appreciate any answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<select id="parents">
@foreach (var source in Model.Sources)
{
     <option>@source</option>
}
</select>

@foreach (var source in Model.Sources)
{
    <select id="@source.ParentName_children" class="childselect">
        @foreach (var child in source.ChildNames)
        {
            <option>@child</option>
        }
    </select>
}
```

This will render one select list for all the parents and then one select for each parent's children (with a unique id). Then in jQuery you can do something like this:

```
$("#parents").change(function () {
     var selectedValue = $("#parents").val();
     // Hide all the selects for children
      $(".childselect").hide(); 

      // show the one that belongs to this parent
     $("#" + selectedValue + "_children").show(); 
});
```

To make sure that not all child selects are visible when the page loads you can add this CSS rule:

```
.childselect{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply! It seems to be the simplest solution! I've just change the child `select` `id` according Razor concatenation to `select id="children_@source.ParentName"` and its selector into jQuery-code: `$("#children_" + selectedValue).show();`

Comment: I edited my answer so that all are hidden when the page initially loads